# How to change the color of replacement text as html in VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba

I'm trying to change the color of the variable text "full_name" to bold blue and "replace_week_number" to bold red in the code below. Also I'd like to add a line between J1 and J2 and the table. I have to do this for two of our other locations so I'd like it to be perfect the first time.

I'm very new to VBA and HTML and not familiar with proper syntax needed to achieve this. I have tried several things to change the colors but was unsuccessful. I also added in the extra line between J1 and J2 but they didn't come out that way in the emails I was testing.

```
Sub SendEmail(what_address As String, subject_line As String, mail_body As String)

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    olMail.To = what_address
    olMail.Subject = subject_line
    olMail.HTMLbody = mail_body
    olMail.Send

End Sub

Sub SendSchedules()

row_number = 3

Do
DoEvents
    row_number = row_number + 1
    Dim mail_body_message As String
    Dim full_name As String
    Dim replace_Monday As String
    Dim replace_Tuesday As String
    Dim replace_Wednesday As String
    Dim replace_Thursday As String
    Dim replace_Friday As String
    Dim replace_Saturday As String
    Dim replace_Sunday As String
    Dim StrBody As String

    full_name = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & row_number)
    mon_day = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & row_number)
    tues_day = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & row_number)
    wednes_day = ActiveSheet.Range("D" & row_number)
    thurs_day = ActiveSheet.Range("E" & row_number)
    fri_day = ActiveSheet.Range("F" & row_number)
    satur_day = ActiveSheet.Range("G" & row_number)
    sun_day = ActiveSheet.Range("H" & row_number)
    week_number = ActiveSheet.Range("K2")


    mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_name_here", full_name)
    mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_week_number", week_number)
    mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_Monday", mon_day)
    mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_Tuesday", tues_day)
    mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_Wednesday", wednes_day)
    mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_Thursday", thurs_day)
    mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_Friday", fri_day)
    mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_Saturday", satur_day)
    mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_Sunday", sun_day)


    StrBody = "<html> <head> <style> br, table, table style {background-color: transparent;table background: url(https://imgur.com/a/Yg8oqcn);width: 325px;height: 315px;border: 1px solid black}, th {bpadding: 1px; border: 1px solid black;alignment: center}, td {bpadding: 3px; border: 1px solid black;alignment: center} </style> <head> <body> <table>"
    mail_body_message = ActiveSheet.Range("J1") & " " & vbNewLine & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("J2") & " " & vbNewLine & " " & StrBody & vbNewLine & _
        "<tr>" & _
            "<th>" & ActiveSheet.Range("B3") & "</th>" & _
            "<th>" & ActiveSheet.Range("B2") & "</th>" & _
            "<td>" & mon_day & "</td></tr>" & _
            "<th>" & ActiveSheet.Range("C3") & "</th>" & _
            "<th>" & ActiveSheet.Range("C2") & "</th>" & _
            "<td>" & tues_day & "</td></tr>" & _
            "<th>" & ActiveSheet.Range("D3") & "</th>" & _
            "<th>" & ActiveSheet.Range("D2") & "</th>" & _
            "<td>" & wednes_day & "</td></tr>" & _
            "<th>" & ActiveSheet.Range("E3") & "</th>" & _
            "<th>" & ActiveSheet.Range("E2") & "</th>" & _
            "<td>" & thurs_day & "</td></tr>" & _
            "<th>" & ActiveSheet.Range("F3") & "</th>" & _
            "<th>" & ActiveSheet.Range("F2") & "</th>" & _
            "<td>" & fri_day & "</td></tr>" & _
            "<th>" & ActiveSheet.Range("G3") & "</th>" & _
            "<th>" & ActiveSheet.Range("G2") & "</th>" & _
            "<td>" & satur_day & "</td></tr>" & _
            "<th>" & ActiveSheet.Range("H3") & "</th>" & _
            "<th>" & ActiveSheet.Range("H2") & "</th>" & _
            "<td>" & sun_day & "</td></tr>" & _
            "</table>"

    mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_name_here", full_name)
    mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_week_number", week_number)

    Call SendEmail(ActiveSheet.Range("I" & row_number), ActiveSheet.Range("L1"), mail_body_message)
Loop Until row_number = 74
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
 mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_name_here", full_name)
```

and

```
mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_week_number", week_number)
```

with

```
 mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_name_here", "<span style=" &"""" & "color: #0000ff;" & """" & " full_name & ">")
```

and

```
mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_week_number", "<span style=" &"""" & "color: #ff0000;" & """" & " week_number & ">")
```

To set a line space, you could use the tag

```
<br/>
```

(maybe twice)

Comment: Well, it's adding the spaces and it's changing the color but it's not replacing the name or week number.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your information and your provided code I have tried to understand your scenario.

Going through your provided code, I have ended up with some questions and comments.

Also based on my asumtions of your scenario I have made a suggestion of how to solve the task. I might have missunderstand your scenario and if so is the case I still hope the suggested code will help in building your solution.

For your concreet questions about HTML (email) formatting I have provided two tools I've made and that I use myself for similar tasks.
One is a simple string builder that will make the task of building the HTML-text/code much easier and more controllable.
Second is a function to format text in HTML-texts with color, background color and font weight.

Questions and comments to your provided code:

```
Sub SendEmail(what_address As String, subject_line As String, mail_body As String)

    Dim olApp As New Outlook.Application ' New was missing...
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    olMail.To = what_address
    olMail.Subject = subject_line
    olMail.HTMLbody = mail_body
    olMail.Send

End Sub 'SendEmail


Sub SendSchedules()

' COMMENT: This parameter is not declared. -----
    row_number = 3

    Do
        DoEvents
        row_number = row_number + 1

        Dim mail_body_message As String
        Dim full_name As String

' COMMENT: These are never used... -------------
        Dim replace_Monday As String
        Dim replace_Tuesday As String
        Dim replace_Wednesday As String
        Dim replace_Thursday As String
        Dim replace_Friday As String
        Dim replace_Saturday As String
        Dim replace_Sunday As String
'-----------------------------------------------

        Dim StrBody As String

' COMMENT: Here follows parameters that are not declared. -----
        full_name = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & row_number)
        mon_day = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & row_number)
        tues_day = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & row_number)
        wednes_day = ActiveSheet.Range("D" & row_number)
        thurs_day = ActiveSheet.Range("E" & row_number)
        fri_day = ActiveSheet.Range("F" & row_number)
        satur_day = ActiveSheet.Range("G" & row_number)
        sun_day = ActiveSheet.Range("H" & row_number)
        week_number = ActiveSheet.Range("K2")
'--------------------------------------------------------------

' COMMENTS:------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Why is this done?
' At this stage will not the parameter mail_body_message be an empty string?
' Will this do anything at all?
        mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_name_here", full_name)
        mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_week_number", week_number)
        mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_Monday", mon_day)
        mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_Tuesday", tues_day)
        mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_Wednesday", wednes_day)
        mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_Thursday", thurs_day)
        mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_Friday", fri_day)
        mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_Saturday", satur_day)
        mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_Sunday", sun_day)
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        StrBody = "<html> <head> <style> br, table, table style {background-color: transparent;table background: url(https://imgur.com/a/Yg8oqcn);width: 325px;height: 315px;border: 1px solid black}, th {bpadding: 1px; border: 1px solid black;alignment: center}, td {bpadding: 3px; border: 1px solid black;alignment: center} </style> <head> <body> <table>"
        mail_body_message = ActiveSheet.Range("J1") & " " & vbNewLine & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("J2") & " " & vbNewLine & " " & StrBody & vbNewLine & _
            "<tr>" & _
                "<th>" & ActiveSheet.Range("B3") & "</th>" & _
                "<th>" & ActiveSheet.Range("B2") & "</th>" & _
                "<td>" & mon_day & "</td></tr>" & _
                "<th>" & ActiveSheet.Range("C3") & "</th>" & _
                "<th>" & ActiveSheet.Range("C2") & "</th>" & _
                "<td>" & tues_day & "</td></tr>" & _
                "<th>" & ActiveSheet.Range("D3") & "</th>" & _
                "<th>" & ActiveSheet.Range("D2") & "</th>" & _
                "<td>" & wednes_day & "</td></tr>" & _
                "<th>" & ActiveSheet.Range("E3") & "</th>" & _
                "<th>" & ActiveSheet.Range("E2") & "</th>" & _
                "<td>" & thurs_day & "</td></tr>" & _
                "<th>" & ActiveSheet.Range("F3") & "</th>" & _
                "<th>" & ActiveSheet.Range("F2") & "</th>" & _
                "<td>" & fri_day & "</td></tr>" & _
                "<th>" & ActiveSheet.Range("G3") & "</th>" & _
                "<th>" & ActiveSheet.Range("G2") & "</th>" & _
                "<td>" & satur_day & "</td></tr>" & _
                "<th>" & ActiveSheet.Range("H3") & "</th>" & _
                "<th>" & ActiveSheet.Range("H2") & "</th>" & _
                "<td>" & sun_day & "</td></tr>" & _
                "</table>"

' COMMENT: Why is this done? Both full_name and week_number is defined previously in the code. -------
'          Why not use them directly where they are needed in the email?
        mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_name_here", full_name)
        mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_week_number", week_number)
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        Call SendEmail(ActiveSheet.Range("I" & row_number), ActiveSheet.Range("L1"), mail_body_message)

    Loop Until row_number = 74

End Sub 'SendSchedules
```

My suggestion to solve the task is based on the following assumption of your excel sheet:
[Snapshot of sheet setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bG2tg.png)

My suggestion code for SendSchedules():

```
Sub SendSchedules()

    Dim row_number As Integer
    Dim sb As New jlStringBuilder 'Defining a string builder which will make the construction of the HTML-text easier.

    sb.DefaultLineShift = "<br/>" 'Defining the string builder line break as <br/> since we will use it only for HTML.

    For row_number = 4 To 74 'iterat through row 4 to 74

        'DoEvents

        Dim full_name As String
        Dim week_number As String
        full_name = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & row_number)
        week_number = ActiveSheet.Range("K2")

        sb.Clear 'resets the stringbuilder for new email.

        'Start building the email's HTMLtext.
        sb.AddLine "<html>"

        sb.Add "<head>"

            sb.Add "<style>"
                sb.Add "table {"
                    sb.Add "background-color: transparent;"
                    sb.Add "table background: url(https://i.imgur.com/RUwLFqH.png);" 'Don't think this will work...
                    sb.Add "width: 325px;"
                    sb.Add "height: 315px;"
                    sb.Add "border-collapse: collapse;"
                    sb.Add "border: 1px solid black;"
                sb.Add "},"

                sb.Add "th {"
                    sb.Add "padding: 1px;"
                    sb.Add "text-align: left;"
                    sb.Add "border: 1px solid black;"
                sb.Add "},"

                sb.Add "td {"
                    sb.Add "padding: 3px;"
                    sb.Add "text-align : center;"
                    sb.Add "border: 1px solid black;"
                sb.Add "}"
            sb.Add "</style>"

        sb.Add "</head>"

        sb.Add "<body>"

        'Moved the following to the inside of the HTML code since the whole email text will be delivered as HTML to olMail.HTMLbody:

        'Adding the full_name and week_number so it will apear at the top of the email.
        'Using GetColoredHTMLstring to add color and font weight.
        sb.AddLine GetColoredHTMLstring(full_name, "#0000ff", "", "bold") 'blue and bold font
        sb.AddLine "Week number: "
        sb.Add GetColoredHTMLstring(week_number, "#ff0000", "", "") 'red font

        'COMMENT: I'm guessing this will equal ActiveSheet.Range("J1") and ActiveSheet.Range("J2") in the original setup?

        ' Start building our table.
        sb.AddLine "<table>"

        'Iterating through each range with weekday/chedule data and adding the headings and data rows and columns to the table.
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 2 To 8 'the chedule data is in column 2 (B) to 8 (H).
            sb.Add "<tr>"
                sb.Add "<th>" & ActiveSheet.Cells(3, i) & "</th>" 'Day header 2
                sb.Add "<th>" & ActiveSheet.Cells(2, i) & "</th>" 'Day header 1
                sb.Add "<td>" & ActiveSheet.Cells(row_number, i) & "</td>" 'Day info
            sb.Add "</tr>"
        Next

        'Explanation of what's going on in the loop above:

            'Register info for monday.
            '"B3" = Cells(3,2)
            '"B2" = Cells(2,2)
            'mon_day = Cells(2, row_number)

            ''Register info for tuesday.
            '"C3" = Cells(3,3)
            '"C2" = Cells(2,3)
            'tues_day = Cells(3, row_number)

            ''Register info for wednesday.
            '"D3" = Cells(3,4)
            '"D2" = Cells(2,4)
            'wednes_day = Cells(4, row_number)

        ' ...and so on... throught to Range(8,...

        'Setting end tags for our email HTMLtext.
        sb.Add "</table>" 'end table
        sb.Add "</body>" 'end body
        sb.Add "</html>" 'end html

        'The stringbuilder will now contain the full HTML email, and we pass it to the SendEmail method
        'toghether with the email address and the email subject.
        Call SendEmail(ActiveSheet.Range("I" & row_number), ActiveSheet.Range("L1"), sb.ToString)

    Next 'row_number

End Sub 'SendSchedules
```

The following function is used to format / color HTML-text. You must paste this into you project. Either in a new module or in the same module as the SendSchedules() method.

```
'// Function to render a text packed inside a html <span> tag which has
'// a style attribute defining the text color, text background color and
'// font weight.

Public Function GetColoredHTMLstring(text As String, color As String, backgrColor As String, fontWeigh As String) As String

    Dim sb As New jlStringBuilder

    sb.AddLine "<span style=" & Chr(34)

    If Len(backgrColor) > 0 Then
        sb.Add "background-color:"
        sb.Add backgrColor
        sb.Add ";"
    End If

    If Len(color) > 0 Then
        sb.Add "color:"
        sb.Add color
        sb.Add ";"
    End If

    If Len(fontWeigh) > 0 Then
        sb.Add "font-weight:"
        sb.Add fontWeigh
        sb.Add ";"
    End If

    sb.Add Chr(34) & ">"
    sb.Add text
    sb.Add "</span>"

    GetColoredHTMLstring = sb.ToString

End Function 'GetColoredHTMLstring
```

The suggested code to solve the task uses a string builder class. To implement this, make a new class in your project and name it jlStringBuilder. Then paste the following code into the new class:

```
Option Explicit
'//-----------------------------
'// Code by Jan Lægreid - 2018
'//-----------------------------
'// Updated: 01.11.2018
'//-----------------------------
'// Class for a string builder object that can
'// be used to build a text in a structured way.

Private totalString As String
Private defaultLS As String

'// Property to set the default lineshift for the string builder..
Property Get DefaultLineShift() As String
    DefaultLineShift = defaultLS
End Property
Property Let DefaultLineShift(lineShift As String)
    defaultLS = lineShift
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    'If not spesified, default line shift will default to Chr(13).
    defaultLS = Chr(13)
End Sub

'// Appends a string.
Public Sub Add(text As String)
    totalString = totalString & text
End Sub

'// Adds a line with line shift.
'// Parameters:
'//    textLine : string to be added.
'//    lineShift: spesifies the line shift if it should be different than the default sat for the string
'//               builder. Default is sat by property DefaultLineShift, and defautls to Chr(13) if not
'//               spesified. Sometimes when building a string one might need a different line shift than
'//               the one sat as default for the string builder. For example one would want "<br> if some
'//               of the text is HTML, or if eg. Chr(10) should be used in stead of Chr(13) some place in
'//               the text.
Public Sub AddLine(Optional textLine As String = "", Optional lineShift As String = "")
    If Len(lineShift) = 0 Then lineShift = defaultLS
    If Len(totalString) > 0 Then textLine = lineShift & textLine
    totalString = totalString & textLine
End Sub

'// Retruns the total build string.
Function ToString() As String
    ToString = totalString
End Function

'// Returns the total build string as an array.
Function ToArray() As String()
    ToString = Split(totalString, defaultLS)
End Function

'// Clears the string builder.
Public Sub Clear()
    totalString = ""
End Sub
```

Hope this was to some help.